# Different dependencies for different SDKs and flavors

Tags: android, dependencies, build.gradle, android-productflavors, mopub

In my Android app (build.gradle), I'm using a default config with two product flavors (two APKs):

```
defaultConfig {
applicationId "xyz"
minSdkVersion 16
targetSdkVersion 29
versionCode 20200410
}
```

//

```
flavorDimensions "version"
    productFlavors {
        freeVersion {
            dimension "version"
            applicationId "xyz.free"
            versionName "1.0.0 Free"
        }
        paidVersion {
            dimension "version"
            applicationId "xyz.pro"
            versionName "1.0.0 Pro"
        }
    }
```

The **freeVersion** flavor is showing ads, so I'm using using misc. specific dependencies to MoPub ads network, e.g.:

```
freeVersionImplementation('com.mopub:mopub-sdk-interstitial:5.10.0') { transitive = true }
```

Now, the problem is that MoPub has recently set minSdkVersion to 21. However, I'd still like to support older Android versions down to minSdkVersion 16.

So, what I basically need is the following…

1. minSdkVersion 16 with MoPub dependencies to the **old** MoPub SDK(freeVersion flavor).
2. minSdkVersion 21 with MoPub depencdencies to the **new** MoPub SDK (freeVersion flavor).
3. mindSdkVersion 16 withouth MoPub dependencies (paidVersion flavor)

How can I achieve such a setup in build.gradle? Will I have three APKs in the end or can this be solved with just two APKs?